# Any option to disable 振仮名?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was trying to clip some good answers to my notebook application. The problem is the 振仮名 will be copied together with the 漢字.

The original text:
[image]

When pasted onto the notebook application:
[image]

Comment: There used to be an [option for this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1488/5010), but I cannot find it now...

Comment: As a workaround, try copying the text using Firefox instead of a Chromium-based browser.  Firefox won't copy the furigana.

Comment: Good workaround. Copying text using Firefox works.